# Flex + XML + dataProvider : Problem specifying dataProvider to ComboBox & DataGrid

Tags: xml, apache-flex

I get a XML Response from a PHP Script which I access using [lastResult] property.
The problem is the follwing:
XML Structure:

```
<Main>
  <Category1>
    <Data Name="Data1">
      <Item>
        <Name>foo</Name>
        <Info>bar</Info>
      </Item>
      <Item>
        <Name>baz</Name>
        <Info>FOO</Info>
      </Item>
    </Data>
    <Data Name="Data2">
    </Data>
  </Category1>
  <Category2>
    </Category2>
</Main>
```

Now I specify the dataProvider for the DataGrid as

```
'lastResult.Category1.Data.(@Name == "Data1").Item'
```

This works fine enough & my data is correctly outputted. The only thing I need is that how can I access the @Name property of the `<Data>` tag.
I can output Name & Info of Items by specifying:

```
'Name'
'Info'
```

But I'm clueless how to specify the @Name attribute of the parent `<Data>` tag when I've selected Data.Item as the dataProvider.

From what I can make of it, I need to go up 1 level to the parent node, but I couldn't find any reference so as how to go up one level while using [lastResult] dataProvider (all were using XMLListCollection::parent())
Any help is appreciated.

Regards,
Nisheeth Barthwal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`lastResult.Category1.Data.(@Name == "Data1").Item` gives you XMLList of Items found in Data1. Each item is of type XML and you can call `parent()` function get parent node:

```
//get first item
var item:XML = lastResult.Category1.Data.(@Name == "Data1").Item[0];
trace("Data.@Name: " + item.parent().@Name);
```

**Edit:** to make it work inside DataGrid, you need to use `labelFunction` property of column. Set it to this:

```
function formatItem(item:Object, column:DataGridColumn):String {
    return (item as XML).parent().@Name;
}
```

Comment: But I want to use it inside dataField property of DataGrid.
dataField = "parent().@Name" does not work, neither does dataField = "(parent().@Name)" when dataProvider = "{lastResult.Category1.Data.(@Name == "Data1").Item}"

Comment: Edit: This works in the dataProvider field within {..} (lastResult.Category1.Data.(@Name == "Data1").Item.parent()}
but not in dataField within "" (quotes) ("parent().@Name")